# Getting array from std:vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What is the easiest way of getting a char array from a vector?

The way I am doing is getting a string initialized using vector begin and end iterators, and then getting .c_str() from this string. Are there other efficient methods?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This was discussed in Scott Meyers' *Effective STL*, that you can do `&vec[0]` to get the address of the first element of an `std::vector`, and since the standard constrains vectors to having contiguous memory, you can do stuff like this.

```
// some function
void doSomething(char *cptr, int n)
{

}

// in your code
std::vector<char> chars;

if (!chars.empty())
{
    doSomething(&chars[0], chars.size());
}
```

edit: From the comments (thanks casablanca)

- be wary about holding pointers to this data, as the pointer can be invalidated if the vector is modified.

Comment: +1 but beware that the pointer may become invalid if the vector is modified later.

Answer (score 59):

```
std::vector<char> chars;
char* char_arr = chars.data(); // &chars[0]
```

Comment: `data()` isn't part of the standard STL specification.

Comment: It is part of the new C++0x STL (implemented both in MVSC and GCC), and should be used over &chars[0] if your compiler supports it.

Comment: @ronag: Why should it be preferred? Just because of readability or do other reasons exist?

Comment: @casablanca http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/ and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data   (since C++11)