# How can I convert a std::vector<float> to a float array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting array from std:vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289612/getting-array-from-stdvector)

I've been reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289612/getting-array-from-stdvector) and found them useful, but how can I do the same with a float type?

Comment: Why would that not work for `float` items?

Comment: That accepted answer applies to this question just as well as it would for any other data type. Thus voting to close as a dup.

Answer (score 12):

The same thing.

```
std::vector<float> v(10);
float *p = &v[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

In exactly the way econoclast demonstrated on the answer you quoted.

```
std::vector<float> v;
v.push_back(1.2);
v.push_back(3.4);

// &v[0] is a pointer to the first element of the vector.

float* array_sort_of = &v[0];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    std::cout << array_sort_of[i] << " ";
}

// Output: 1.2 3.4
```

Comment: `float* arr = v.data();`

Comment: @x4444 I prefer `&v[0]` but yes that works too

Comment: `std::vector::data` is a standard way to get direct pointer to the memory array used internally by the vector (since c++11). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/ . That method was added to C++11 for a reason. If you programming in modern C++ I'd recommend to use standard way of doing things.