# Array from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, unity-game-engine, interop

I am trying to pass a double array (its actually a std::vector, but converted at transfer) from a c++ dll into a c# script (unity). 
Using the approach outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31418775.

I can successfully get the size of the array printing on my console in unity   however I am not able to use "CoTaskMemAlloc" to allocate memory for the array since I am using Xcode and it doesnt seem to have COM.

For a little more background this array is part of a control for a GUI, c++ creates it and the user edits with the c# GUI - so the plan is to be able to pass the array back to c++ when it has been edited.

```
C++ code
extern "C" ABA_API void getArray(long* len, double **data){
    *len = delArray.size();
    auto size = (*len)*sizeof(double);
    *data = static_cast<double*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(size));
    memcpy(*data, delArray.data(), size);
}

C# code 
[DllImport("AudioPluginSpecDelay")]
private static extern void getArray (out int length,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] out double[] array);

int theSize;
double[] theArray;
getArray(out theSize, out theArray);
```

If I leave out the code concerning the array, the int passes just fine. So I beleive the method to be the right one, its just getting around the lack of CoTaskMemAlloc.

Comment: are you saying you are not sure what to do on the c++ side, or, on the c# side? where is the problem?

Comment: Hey, the problem is with CoTaskMemAlloc which allocates the memory for the array (and it HAS to be CoTaskMemAlloc, i tried with other memory allocations and it didn't work). It does not exist on mac! as yms pointed out below GLib is supposedly the alternative for mac.

I am open to other methods that do not use GLib :)

Comment: You could also do all memory management on the C# side :)

Comment: hi @k9256 -  I wanted to ask you something.  Just FWIW, *what are you actually trying to do*?  FYI: it's extremely common with Unity that: experienced programmers (like yourself), who are fooling around with Unity, "accidentally" as it were go down the path of trying to do something, unaware that there is a ridiculously simple way to achieve said thing in the Unity milieu. Just as a curiosity what are you actually trying to do?  Cheers

Comment: Hey Joe, I am currently making a spectral delay audio plugin using the unity native audio SDK. The array that is going between c++/c# are delay time arrays so the user can choose different times for each bin of the FFT(which is in C++) with a GUI. Its my first time using the SDK, and tbh I haven't used C++ a lot. So learning best practices with both at the same time is challenging!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to allocate memory in XCode using `malloc` and free it in C# using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`. To be able to free it however, you need to have the IntPtr for it:

C++ code

```
extern "C" ABA_API void getArray(long* len, double **data)
{
    *len = delArray.size();
    auto size = (*len)*sizeof(double);
    *data = static_cast<double*>(malloc(size));
    memcpy(*data, delArray.data(), size);
}
```

C# code

```
[DllImport("AudioPluginSpecDelay")]
private static extern void getArray(out int length, out IntPtr array);

int theSize;
IntPtr theArrayPtr;
double[] theArray;

getArray(out theSize, out theArrayPtr);
Marshal.Copy(theArrayPtr, theArray, 0, theSize);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(theArrayPtr);

// theArray is a valid managed object while the native array is already freed
```

**Edit**

From [Memory Management](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#memory-management) I gathered that `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` would most likely be implemented using `free()`, so the fitting allocator would be `malloc()`.

There are two ways to be really sure:

1. Allocate the memory in CLI using `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem`, pass it to native to have it filled, and then free it in the CLI again using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.
2. Leave it as it is (native allocates memory with `malloc()`), but do not free the memory in CLI. Instead, have another native function like `freeArray(double **data)` and have it `free()` the array for you once CLI is done using it.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, I was getting far too caught up in following the other method perfectly to think about doing this! Thanks.

Comment: @k9256 I am not sure this is correct... you will be allocating with one function and de-allocating with a different (possibly unrelated) function. At least try to make sure that your code is not leaking memory, even if it looks like "it works"

Comment: Just checked, the memory usage for Unity does creep up when I am using the GUI I have made. I tried adding free(*data) in c++, but this causes a crash. Do you suggestions on where to look to stop memory leakage?

Comment: I am now not sure about memory leakage, Unity seems to creep up on its own without my plugin present.

Would Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(arrayPtr) not free the memory allocated by C++? I know that I should be using CoTaskMemAlloc in C++, but I am not entirely clear on the difference

Comment: I struggle to see why you wouldn't have all malloc/free pairs be completely self-contained in the iOS side.  For that matter - who has used memory management in iOS for what 10 years?  Just program "properly" in a modern manner you know??  :O

Comment: As the first approach was to free the memory in CLI, programming it "properly" - which I understand to mean ``new`` and ``delete`` - won't work, because they contain extra logic the CLI does not know about. So the solution had to be restricted to plain memory allocation. Feel free to post an answer proposing a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert on Unity, but it seems that [Unity relies on Mono for it's C# scripting support](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51350/how-does-unity-use-c-as-a-scripting-language). Take a look at this documentation page:

[Memory Management in Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#memory-management)

We can assume from there that you will need to have platform-dependent code on your C++ side, you will need to use CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree in Windows and  GLib memory functions g_malloc() and g_free() for Unix (like iOS, Android etc).

If you have control over all your code, C++ and C#, the easiest way to implement this would be to do all the memory allocation/deallocation in the C# script.

Sample code (untested):

```
//C++ code

extern "C" ABA_API long getArrayLength(){
    return delArray.size();
}

extern "C" ABA_API void getArray(long len, double *data){
    if (delArray.size() <= len)
        memcpy(data, delArray.data(), delArray.size());
}

// C# code
[DllImport("AudioPluginSpecDelay")]
private static extern int getArrayLength(); 

[DllImport("AudioPluginSpecDelay")]
private static extern void getArray(int length,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] double[] array);

int theSize = getArrayLength();
double[] theArray = new double[theSize];
getArray(theSize, theArray);
```

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the doc link, I am attempting to get GLib now. I am not hugely confident in C++ so I wish I didnt have to, but it seems unavoidable!