# C# List of Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, clr

I want to map some C++ to C# via CLI/C++. In C++ I have a `vector<map<string,string>>` which I thought I could represent in .Net as `List<Dictionary<String,String>`. However, this gives me errors.

```
List<Dictionary<String,String>> // is not a valid generic argument
```

Is there a standard alternative?

Note I'm implementing this in CLI/C++.

Comment: Does anything in here help? Not too familiar with C++, but while a vector and map may behave like a List and Dictionary in C#, they are different types which is important when doing interop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417688/passing-a-vector-array-from-unmanaged-c-to-c-sharp

Comment: "gives me errors", please post the actual error messages you're getting and the whole code, there should be no error message from the code you've posted. Also, if the error is that you're trying to figure out what to call a C++ method with, from C#, can you please tell us what intellisense says about the whole thing? I think it should tell you what the types of things should be even in this scenario.

Comment: The error is there. Not a valid generic arg...

Comment: The snippet is entirely too short to see the problem, but one obvious mistake (if this is C++/CLI code) is that you forgot to use the ^ hat.  Required on reference types.  So it is `List<Dictionary<String^, String^>^>^ arg`.  Converting to the unmanaged collection types is something you'll have to do yourself, one element at a time.  A painful and slow affair.

Comment: I'm afc now but I'm pretty sure I tried that. Will confirm when I get back. Re the conversions - yup... Pretty tedious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need to pass handles to generic containers:

```
List<Dictionary<String^, String^>^>^ list_of_dict_of_string;
```

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one `>` This may be a Typo, Any way the declaration should be like this:

```
List<Dictionary<String,String>> DictList = new List<Dictionary<String,String>>();
```

You can initialize then like this:

```
List<Dictionary<String, String>> DictList = new List<Dictionary<String, String>>()
                                        {
                                            new Dictionary<String,String>()
                                            {
                                                {"Key 1","value 1" },
                                                {"Key 2","value 2" }
                                            },
                                            new Dictionary<String,String>()
                                            {
                                                {"Key 1","value 1" },
                                                {"Key 2","value 2" }
                                            }
                                        };
```