# Passing List<int*[]> from c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have spent a lot of days trying to solve this problem. I have a c++ dll function that takes as a parameter a "std::vector<int*> *list", I need to pass a compatible pointer from c# in Unity.
I tried in this way:

**UPDATE**
**c++ code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#if _MSC_VER 
#define EXPORT_API  
#else
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

extern "C"{
    /* Other function */
 

    EXPORT_API void GetBlocks(std::vector<int*> *list, int* listSize){
                
        list->push_back(std::vector<int>(16*16*16, 1).data());
        (*block_size)++;
    }

}
```

**c# code:**

```
[DllImport("dllLib", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
unsafe private static extern void GetBlocks(ref List<int*[]> block, ref int blockSize);

void Start() {
    int blockSize = 0;
    List<int*[]> block = new List<int*[]>();

    unsafe
    {
        GetBlocks(ref block, ref blockSize);
    }
}
```

Unity returns this error:

*MarshalDirectiveException: Type System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int*[]> which is passed to unmanaged code must have a StructLayout attribute.
*

I suppose that I have to manage somehow the conversion using Marshal, but right now I don't know.
Maybe there could be another type instead of List<int*[]> to pass a list of the pointer to an array.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is you r c++ dll managed or unmanaged?  A managed c++ does not need DllImport.  You can call the c++ methods like any c# method.

Comment: If I understood the difference between managed and unmanaged, my c++ is unmanaged. For completeness, I add the code listing in the main massage

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417688/passing-a-vector-array-from-unmanaged-c-to-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks I try to adapt that solution to my case