# vector<Mat> to single array without any explict loops

Tags: c++, opencv, stdvector

I have a vector of opencv Mat images (*std::vector imgVec*) and I need to copy the data from all Mat inside the vector to a single float array (float *). The images are already float images (CV_32F).

**First, I tried to use just imgVec.data()**, but the compiler tells that

> *a value of type cv::Mat* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type float**

**Then, a tried to use std::copy**, but I didn't seem to work as well.

Thus, my question is:

How can I copy the contents of all cv::Mat inside a std::vector into a single float array (without any explict loops)?

Comment: What do you mean by "without any explicit loops" ?

Comment: May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289612/getting-array-from-stdvector) helps you?

Comment: @RickM. That's useless in here, since each of the `Mat`s holds a pointer to a separately allocated array which holds that data. It's this data that's of interest.

Comment: @DanMašek True that, without _explicit loops_ (don't know exactly what OP means here), it would be difficult. What I can think of is using [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Comment: I suppose [`cv::vconcat`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga558e169e15adcc46b8cdcc6cd215070f) to merge them all into one `cv::Mat` (assuming all of them have the same number of columns and channels, the OP is not very informative). The rest would be trivial. | The "explicit loops" would probably be more efficient -- count total number of elements, reserve the space in vector, copy one by one.

Comment: you can try cv::merge, then each matrix will build a channel of the result matrix.

Comment: @Micka I considered that too for a moment, but wouldn't that end up with a memory layout where the matrices are interleaved? Not sure if that's desirable. Also, if there's a lot of them, might hit the channel limit (`CV_CN_MAX`) of 512....

Comment: @Micka, that was what I did. I merged all Mat in vector into a variable mergedMat and accessed mergedMat.data. Thank you!